# Odds of a team winning a sports match given full history

Tags: statistical-significance, prediction, odds-ratio, odds

Assumptions:

- The teams never change
- The teams don't improve in skill
- The entire history of each team's performance against some subset of other teams is known

For example:

I have a long list of match outcomes that look like this:

```
Team A beats Team B
Team B beats Team A
Team A beats Team B
Team C beats Team A
Team A beats Team C
```

Problem:

Predict the correct betting odds of any team beating any other team.

In the example above, maybe we conclude that A should beat B 66% of the time. That is based off direct observation and is pretty straightforward. However, finding the probability that C beats B seems harder. They've never played together, yet it seems like most likely that C > B, with some low confidence.

Comment: Or, just tell me the name of the technique that I should google for. I don't know what the right keywords for this problem are. Thanks!